# SUM of offset cells that contain a value

Tags: excel, google-sheets, sum, formula, countif

I'm trying to make a basic SUM of offsetted cells. Basically I have 4 columns, column A being just a title, column B being a counted number, and columns C and D referencing another value.

The thing I'm trying to accomplish is the number count on column G. It should be a SUM of all of the values in column B IF that number appears in the reference columns

[image]

An example would be that G2 would equal 15, since 1 appears in C2 (so it should add 7 from B2) and D3 (and add 8 from B3).

I have the basic `=COUNTIF` function to count the instances, but how do I reference the value from column B if a value appears in column C or D?

`=COUNTIF(C2:D4,"1")`
`=COUNTIF(C2:D4,"2")`
...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h9PDZii5wO866Hky3P_BZ_SOwuHAAd6qUySkuJ14L6A/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`.

So long as `Reference1` and `Reference2` will not have the same number in the same row:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((($C$2:$C$4=F2)+($D$2:$D$4=F2))*$B$2:$B$4)
```

If it is possible for them to have the same number, but you only want to count the value in the `Count` column once, then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(((($C$2:$C$4=F2)+($D$2:$D$4=F2))>0)*$B$2:$B$4)
```

Comment: Was trying to figure out how to do it using one `SUMPRODUCT` instead of summing two.

Answer (score 1):

`SUMPRODUCT` will get the answer for you as well

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$4,--($C$2:$C$4=F2))+SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$B$4,--($D$2:$D$4=F2))
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Single formula solution:

`=QUERY(
{"Reference #","Number";
TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",0,TRANSPOSE(C2:D4)),",")),
TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(JOIN(",",B2:B4)&",",COLUMNS(C2:D2)),","))},
"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1")`

The result is:

```
Reference #   sum Number
      1             15
      2              2
      3              2
      4              8
      5              7
```